Why do electrons fill the orbitals instead of lin.combination?
In a multi electron atom we start by filling the states 1s, 2s, 2p etc. For the 2p state, we have 2px,2py,2pz, and we fill each one with an electron. Since the 2p state is degenerate, I do not understand why the fillings of the electrons cannot be in linear combinations of 2px, 2py, 2pz.
My guess is that this configuration minimizes somehow the energy of the atom because each orbital is concentrated along one axis and therefore there is some symmetry that probably leads to a minimization of the interaction energy of the electrons. But I am not sure about that and cannot quantify it.

Technically there are no pure orbitals like 2p$_z$ for multi electron atoms. This is just a convenient approximation used for teaching students, and the real states can be expressed as complicated linear combinations of orthogonal functions.

Viewing it in the linear combination basis will also show the filling; there is really not that much difference either way. In fact, in molecules, the linear combinations are the ones that are convenient to talk about and use, not the original states.

I hope I am interpreting your question correctly. If I am, then the short answer is that you are right--one can certainly have linear combinations of the above quantum states. However, we need to be careful about what the quantum numbers specifying these orbitals are actually labeling and what it means for them to be degenerate.
In quantum mechanics, states are represented by complex vectors. To choose a basis in which to express a state, we pick some family of mutually commuting observables, whose shared eigenvalues are enough to completely specify the state. In this case, our family of operators is $H, L^2$ and $L_z$, corresponding to the energy, total angular momentum, and angular momentum along the $z$-direction. Then we may write a basis state as $|\psi\rangle = |n,l,m\rangle$, where $H|\psi\rangle = E_n|\psi\rangle$, $E_n$ being the energy levels of the electron, $L^2|\psi\rangle = \hbar^2 l(l+1)|\psi\rangle$, and $L_z|\psi\rangle = \hbar m |\psi\rangle$.
We translate from this to the spectroscopic notation you used by assigning $n$ to the first number, $l=0$ to $s$, $l=1$ to $p$, $l=2$ to $d$, and $l=3$ to $f$, and choosing $z$ to correspond to $m=0$, and assigning $x$ and $y$ to $m= \pm 1$ arbitrarily. In this language, $|n=2, l=1, m=0\rangle$ corresponds to the 2pz orbital. We can specify a superposition of these states as a (normalized) linear combination, such as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|n=2,l=1,m=-1\rangle + |n=2,l=1,m=1\rangle)$. Since these states are eigenstates of observables with distinct eigenvalues, they are necessarily orthogonal.
However, we should step back and think about the meaning of these quantum numbers. In the case you specified, there is a degeneracy in the magnetic quantum number. Since these states are distinguished by their transformation under rotation (which is generated by $L_z$,) this degeneracy is equivalent to saying that the problem is spherically symmetric. Who is to say which direction should be the $z$-direction? In short, without an external field such as a magnetic field coupling to the angular momentum, it does not make much sense to distinguish between these states in the first place! Specifying $m$ only makes sense relative to an external field that breaks the rotational symmetry.
I hope this explanation makes some sense and clears up your concern. If you are seeking further resources, my favorite book on Atomic Physics is by C. J. Foot, and I love the exposition on the theory of angular momentum in the classic Sakurai and Napolitano.
Cheers!

If there is spherical symmetry, the choice of axes x, y and z is arbitrary. A different choice of axes corresponds to a different choice of orthogonal linear combinations. So by not specifying what x, y and z actually mean you already build in this freedom.
